# Python Question: How to add the values per line

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in Python and trying to get my head around on this code.

We have to import a text file named line-items.txt; excerpt of the txt are as follows including its heading:

product name quantity unit price

product a   1   10.00

product b   5   19.70

product a   3   10.00

product b   7   19.70

We need to write a code that will search for the product name and sum its quantity and unit price then the sales revenue formula would be "total unit price of the product" * "total quantity of the product"; we have to create new text file and the output should be something like this:

product name   sales volume    sales revenue
product a   4   40.0
product b   12  236.39999999999998

On my code below it has searched the quantity of product b which is 5 and 7 and its unit price (I did print statement to check its output but on the code below I commented the unit price for simplicity) but it's not adding the values that it has searched:

```
def main():
    # opening file to read line-items.txt
    with open("line-items.txt", "r") as line_items:
    # to get the list of lines and reading the second line of the text
        prod_b = 0
        newtxt = line_items.readlines()[1:]
        for line in newtxt:
            text = line.strip().split()
            product_name = text[0:2]
            quantity = text[2]
            unit_price = text[3]
        if product_name == ['product', 'b']:
            prod_b += int(quantity)
            unit_price_b = float(unit_price)
            # print(unit_price_b)
            print(quantity)
line_items.close()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

The output of the code above are as follows; it's not adding 5 and 7; what am I doing wrong?

5

7

Thanks,

Rogue

Comment: there's a slight typo in my code the print statement should be print(prod_b) NOT print(quantity) but the output is still the same 5 and 7 and doesn't add/sum the quantity that it searched

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by @JonSG is certainly more elegant.  The problem with your code is quite simple and is caused by an indentation error.  You need to indent the if statement under the for loop as shown below:

```
def main():
    # opening file to read line-items.txt
    with open("line-items.txt", "r") as line_items:
    # to get the list of lines and reading the second line of the text
        prod_b = 0
        newtxt = line_items.readlines()[1:]
        for line in newtxt:
            text = line.strip().split()
            product_name = text[0:2]
            quantity = text[2]
            unit_price = text[3]
            if product_name == ['product', 'b']:
                prod_b += int(quantity)
                unit_price_b = float(unit_price)
                # print(unit_price_b)
                print(quantity)
line_items.close()
```

Comment: Hello itprorh66, thank your time in answering my query, I did another print statement for prod_b; that is print(prod_b) and value that shows up now is:

5
12

It's adding up the quantity of b which is 12 but 5 is appearing on first line; how can I remove the first line of the output when its adding up the total quantity?

Comment: Just add-on:

So when I try to print "prod_b" it shows the value of:

5
12

It's adding up the quantity of b which is 12 but 5 is appearing on first line. How can I remove the first line of the output so that only 12 will appear.

In addition, I'm unable to use "+=" when calculating unit_price_b; is there a way to calculate the float values from the text file without creating another function?(I need add the 2 x product b  unit price, i.e. 19.70 + 19.70 to get 39.40 as an output, there's more product name in the text file, I just use product a and product b as a sample). thanks

Comment: I already figure out the unit price, the only remaining issue I have is the output of prod_b since it shows on the first line the value of 5 and the 2nd line, it shows the value of 12 (which is the total value of the product b unit) , I want to get rid of the first line of the output and only want 12 to show up when I do the print statement. Thanks

Comment: Hello Guys, my issue is already resolved, thank you all for your input, itproprh66, you gave me an idea on how to resolve it, I didn't realized that my alignment causing the issue until you said so;in addition, the alignment of my print statement (i.e. print(prod_b) is incorrect which causes the two values to appear, the print statement should be aligned with the for statement not the if statement, it now only show the total value of the not. Jon,  thanks as well for your input, it will help me in my 2nd assignment that involves csv.

Comment: @Rogue if itprorh66's answer helped you, you might think about flagging it as "the answer" and/or indicating it as helpful. Since it seems to have helped you get unstuck I am going to also flag it as helpful.

Comment: @JonSG, as much as I would like to flag this as helpful or answered when I click the flag button, I don't see those options☹, I'm new to this site

Comment: it is the up-arrow top left corner of this answer. You can see the `1` as I already voted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested `collections.defaultdict` makes this problem rather straightforward.

```
import collections
import json

results = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(float))
with open("line-items.txt", "r") as line_items:
    next(line_items) ## skip first line
    for row in line_items.readlines():
        cells = row.split(" ")
        product_name = f"{cells[0]} {cells[1]}"
        quatity = int(cells[2])
        price = float(cells[3])
        results[product_name]["quantity"] += quatity
        results[product_name]["sales volume"] += quatity * price

print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
```

results in:

```
{
    "product a": {
        "quantity": 4.0,
        "sales volume": 40.0
    },
    "product b": {
        "quantity": 12.0,
        "sales volume": 236.4
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for your input but the file that was provided to us in text file and as part of our assignment, we can't use csv; we have to import/read a text file that they have provided to us.

Comment: Hello Jon, thank you for editing but the requirements we have to use the text file that was provided to use, we can't use csv :-(

Comment: @Rogue My update removed the CVS element and uses a text file that is the same format as you provided.

Comment: Sorry I`ve overlooked that csv element has been removed